# Why Are My Links Not Working With Css Transitions And Z-index?

Tags: css

Hoping someone can point me right...

I have been trying all day to figure out how to hide a flash  behind some html elements, and then reveal the flash object when hovering using css transitions.

I came up with two solutions, each is only %50 of what I really want.

The first example transitions when you hover, and you can click the links, but I want it to transition like example two.

The second example transitions the way I want, but anything behind cannot be clicked.

Where did I mess up? Are my z-index(s) not getting parsed in example two?

Examples: http://jsfiddle.net/zyD4D/

HTML:

```
    <object> <a href="#" title="Links Work">Links Work</a>

        <br /><a href="#" title="But Curtains">But Curtains</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#" title="Are Wrong">Are Wrong</a>

    </object>
</div>
<hr>
<div id="theatre2"> <em id="curtain-left2"></em>
    <em id="curtain-right2"></em>

    <object> <a href="#" title="Links Don't Work">Links Don't Work</a>

        <br /><a href="#" title="But Curtains">But Curtains</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#" title="Are Right">Are Right</a>

    </object>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div#theatre {
    border: inset black 0px;
    height: 425px;
    width: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 120px;
    font-size: 30px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: black;
}
div#theatre #curtain-left {
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 50%;
    background: url(http://s27.postimg.org/dznawniab/curtain_left.jpg) 0px 0px no-repeat;
    transition: all 4s ease;
    background-size: 100%;
}
div#theatre #curtain-right {
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 50%;
    background: url(http://s27.postimg.org/9ozg9kyfn/curtain_right.jpg) 0px 0px no-repeat;
    transition: all 4s ease;
    background-size: 100%;
}
#curtain-left {
    left: 0;
}
#curtain-right {
    right: 0;
}
div#theatre:hover #curtain-right {
    width: 0;
    background-size: 1px;
    transition: all 4s ease;
}
div#theatre:hover #curtain-left {
    width: 0;
    background-size: 1px;
    transition: all 4s ease;
}
div#theatre2 {
    border: inset black 0px;
    height: 425px;
    width: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 120px;
    font-size: 30px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: black;
}
div#theatre2 #curtain-left2 {
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 50%;
    transition-property:background-position;
    transition-duration:2s;
    transition-timing-function:ease-out;
    background: url(http://s27.postimg.org/dznawniab/curtain_left.jpg) 0px 0px no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
}
div#theatre2 #curtain-right2 {
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 50%;
    transition-property:background-position;
    transition-duration:2s;
    transition-timing-function:ease-out;
    background: url(http://s27.postimg.org/9ozg9kyfn/curtain_right.jpg) 0px 0px no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
}
#curtain-left2 {
    left: 0;
}
#curtain-right2 {
    right: 0;
}
div#theatre2:hover #curtain-right2 {
    transition-property:background-position;
    transition-duration:2s;
    transition-timing-function:ease-out;
    background-position: +301px 0px, left top;
}
div#theatre2:hover #curtain-left2 {
    transition-property:background-position;
    transition-duration:2s;
    transition-timing-function:ease-out;
    background-position: -301px 0px;
}
.object {
    margin: 0.0em auto;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your css to only transition the left and right margins of the left and right curtains respectively.

```
div#theatre #curtain-left {
    ...
    transition: margin-left 4s ease;
    margin-left:0;
    left:0;
    ...
}
div#theatre #curtain-right {
    ...
    transition: margin-right 4s ease;
    margin-right:0;
    right:0;
    ...
}
div#theatre:hover #curtain-right {
    margin-right:-300px;
}
div#theatre:hover #curtain-left {
    margin-left:-300px;
}
```

and remove the background-size change on hover.

I fixed up your fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/zyD4D/2/

Comment: Thanks so much! Working as needed.Is there an example page the goes over a bunch of CSS transition effects? I search a ton of phrases before I came here.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition-timing-function gives you the defaults but a I'll always refer to http://easings.net/ for a greater selection.